# How can I embed html file with D3.js in Confluence that consumes json data

Tags: html, d3.js, confluence

I have D3.js visualization that relies on json file. The D3.js code is part of  HTML file that I want to embed within Atlassian Confluence.

The question is how and where should I put the json file so the visualization will be displayed on the Confluence page correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but it sounds like you are not an admin and just want to load this JSON from a Confluence page without a custom macro. If so, if the JSON file is attached, you can find the  tag that has class `confluence-embedded-file` and `default-alias="your-file.json"`, the href attribute of this tag will be a link to your JSON, and you can fetch it with a Get just like you would normally. 
You could hide the JSON's thumbnail with some CSS as well, just set `display:hidden` on the element.

This all assumes you are not making a macro. If you are, just place the JSON in the macro's resources and include it that way.

Here is what the tag looks like when I embedded a file test.json to a page: [image: Screenshot of Chrome inspector]

Comment: Why use screenshots ?